# Importance of normality of regression residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, normality-assumption

Similar questions have been asked so far. However, none of them gives a solution to my problem.

I am conducting a regression. Unfortunately, the residuals are not normally-distributed. I tried several transformations and adding more explanatory variables. Still, it is not normally distributed. In a book on statistics I read that this is okay if the residual distribution is still symmetric. In my case, the residuals of 12 out of 14 regressions are symmetric. On the other hand, in some statistics books, I read that it is sufficient if the sample size is big enough (due to the Central Limit Theorem). However, there is not really a definition a "large" sample.

Is my model valid if residuals are not normally-distributed but sample size is equal to 100? And does the residual distribution need to be symmetric?
In particular I am interested in the p values, because I need them for inference...

Comment: Are all other relevant assumptions fulfilled?

Comment: Besides distorting statistical inference, non-normality of residuals can often cause non-robust fits.  Least squares in a sense minimizes the maximum prediction errors but can result in too many small errors.

Comment: @Michael M: the residuals are autocorrelated and heteroskedastic, but this is solved with robust estimators...